# Setting default values to array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var patientSchema = new Schema({
    resourceType : {type :String, default : 'Patient' },
    id : {type : String, default : 'example'},
    text : [{
        status : {type : String, default : 'generated'},
        div :{type : String, default :'<div> Something </div>'}
    }],
    active : {type : String, default : 'true'},
    identifier : [{
        use : {type : String, default : 'official'},
        system : {type : String, default : 'urn:oid:1.2.36.146.595.217.0.1'},
        assinger :[{
            display : {type : String, default : 'Acme Healthcare'},
        }]

    }],
    name: [{
        use : {type : String, default : 'official'},
        first_name : {type : String, default : ''},
        second_name : {type : String, default : ''}
    }],
    gender :{type : String,  default : ''},
    birthDate :{type : String,  default : ''},
    telecom : [{
        system : {type : String, default : ''},
        value : {type : String, default : ''}
    }],
    address : [{
        use : {type : String, default : 'official'},
        text : {type : String, default : ''},
        city : {type : String, default : ''},
        district : {type : String, default : ''},
        state : {type : String, default : ''},
        postalcode :{type : String, default : ''}
    }]
});

var patients = mongoose.model('Patients',patientSchema);
module.exports = patients;
```

This is my model class, i'm sending values through post-man tool, 
The default values inside the array of fields eg.

```
text : [{
        status : {type : String, default : 'generated'},
        div :{type : String, default :'<div> Something </div>'}
    }],
```

the status and div are not storing the default values

i need to store the values of status and div as default!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a sub-scheme/document instead!

```
var patientTextSchema = new Schema({ 
   status : {type : String, default : 'generated'},
   div :{type : String, default :'<div> Something </div>'} 
});

... ommited for clarity
var patientSchema = new Schema({
  text: [patientTextSchema]
})
```

This way you you can do patient.text.push({}) for adding a default patientTextSchema, or patient.text.push({status: "another_status"}) for a (partially) filled scheme.

Source: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: So you want me to have the text field as a schema and then push it inside the text field(Asking to make sure i have understood the answer).

Comment: Yes you understood correctly, It looks like a lot more work, but its also reusable, so it saves you time when you want to have a text field somewhere else too!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following way to create Array of Objects with a default in mongoose:

```
const organisationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        brands: {
            type: [
                {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'brand'
                }
            ],
            default: []
        },
        users: {
            type: [
                {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'user'
                }
            ],
            default: []
        }
    }, { timestamps: true });
```